# Angular uiRouter reloads each components in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UIRouter in order to define my app routes and views.

Now what is going wrong is that each time I go to a route, UIRouter reloads every view defined in the "ongoing" route rule, even those which aren't changed from the old route. This cause controllers reset and piss me off. 
I don't want to code those views in my general template, and I would avoid to use manual `<ng-include ng-if="blah">`, so is there any other solution?

Here is my route config. As you can see both routes have the very same views. **Please keep in mind that left, center and right views are placed inside the home.html**, which is assigned to the "home" rule.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/home.html',
      abstract: true,
      views: {
          'header': {
              templateUrl: 'app/components/header/headerView.html'
          },
          '': {
              templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/home.html'
          }
      }
    })
  .state('home.twitter', {
        url: '/home/twitter',
        views:{
            'left': {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/accountList/accountListView.html'
            },
            'center': {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/timeline/timelineView.html'
            },
            'right': {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/accountWallet/accountWalletView.html'
            }
        }
    })
      .state('home.link', {
        url: '/home/link',
        views:{
            'left': {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/accountList/accountListView.html'
            },
            'center': {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/timeline/timelineView.html'
            },
            'right': {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/accountWallet/accountWalletView.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your defined states and transitions, please.

Comment: You should define left, center and right views in your abstract "home" state.

Comment: @henrikmerlander unfortunatly I can't: left center and right are contained inside home.html, that is assigned in the abstract view

Comment: Can't you use the content of home.html in your index.html instead?

Comment: Looks like you need another state layer, which defines just the left and right sides. Unless left and right are the same across different (parent) states, then there is no need to actually put the view template in the state config.

Comment: @Nemus can you share your home.html please, too?

Comment: @S.B. Left and right are actually the same between those two states, but in an hypothetically third state they can be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `left` and `right` are only shared between these 2 states and can be different for other children of `home`, you need another abstract layer to keep them separate from the center view:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home'
    templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/home.html',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/header/headerView.html'
        },
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/home.html'
        }
    }
  })
  .state('home.account', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views:{
        'left': {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/accountList/accountListView.html'
        },
        'center': {
            templateUrl : '<ui-view/>'
        },
        'right': {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/accountWallet/accountWalletView.html'
        }
    }
  })
  .state('home.account.twitter', {
    url: '/twitter',
    views:{
        'center': {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/timeline/timelineView.html'
        }
    }
  })
  .state('home.account.link', {
    url: '/link',
    views:{
        'center': {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/timeline/timelineView.html'
        }
    }
  });
```

When you go from `home.account.twitter` to `home.account.link`, the left and right views should stay the same. That said, it would obviously be better if you could actually integrate the `left` and `right` views into the parent abstract state instead of having a separate state just for them.